# Can I run an electronic piano using a power bank?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging

I have a Yamaha P-140 electronic piano. Looking at its power adapter, I see the following info:

- Input: 230V~ 50Hz 170mA
- Output: 12V (strange symbol here, something like an equal sign `=`, but with dots in the lower line) 1.5A

[image: photo of the power adapter]

I have a new, massive power bank with 45000mAh that I can charge laptops with, so it has a lot of adapters. And I wonder whether it could be used to run the piano as well? Its specs:

- Switchable output: 12V / 3A, 16V / 3A, 20V / 3A

[image: photo of the powerbank]

What do you think? To me (as an absolute newbie to this topic), the option `12V / 3A` looks very close to the needed `12V / 1.5A`, but maybe it would require to match perfectly? Or `3A` is the max, and `1.5A` would fit nicely? I really have no idea.

Comment: Welcome, questions on the usage of electronic devices are not really on topic here.  We also have an established question on power adapter ratings which this will probably be closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: Just FYI, that strange looking equals sign just indicates that the output is DC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work. The amperage of a power supply is the max current that can be drawn, but a load will only use however much current it needs. So having a 3A power supply powering a 1.5A load will work as long as the voltages are the same. The only thing left is to make sure the polarities are the same, since the piano takes a center positive barrel jack, the power bank is almost certainly the same but it's worth a quick check to be sure.